# Plot multivalue (one to many) data with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I have data which shows who is in a photo stored as CSV in a file:

```
|------------+---------------------------|
| image      | people                    |
|------------+---------------------------|
| image1.png | John, Paul                |
| image2.png | John                      |
| image3.png |                           |
| image4.png | George, Paul, John, Ringo |
| ...        |                           |
|------------+---------------------------|
```

I would like to load it into R, and plot this in various ways, but let's say I'd like to get a bar graph that shows how many appearances each person makes.

I can restructure the data if that helps.

Thank you

Comment: what does your data actually look like in R? use `dput(yourdata)` or a subset of your data.  The picture above isn't an R data structure.  However, what you're asking is very straight forward.  Look at `melt` from the `reshape2` package.

Comment: Yeah, this is still in raw format (e.g. CSV).  I'd like to also figure out how best to load it into R.

Comment: can you put a portion of the csv up then?  I assume it doesn't look like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dataset like this describes the situation you mention in your question:

```
require(plyr)
people_list = c("Edward", "Smith", "Neo", "Mr. Anderson", 
                "Red John", "Blackbeard", "Lily", "Anne")
dat = data.frame(image = sprintf("image%d.png", 1:100))
dat = ddply(dat, .(image), function(x) {
  people = sample(people_list, size = sample(1:length(people_list), 1))
  return(data.frame(image = x$image, people))
})
> head(dat)
       image     people
1 image1.png Blackbeard
2 image1.png     Edward
3 image1.png       Anne
4 image1.png       Lily
5 image1.png        Neo
6 image1.png   Red John
```

If you cast your dataset in this shape, you can calculate aggregations from this using `ddply` from `plyr`:

```
# Number of occurences of people
occ = ddply(dat, .(people), summarise, no_occurence = length(people))
> occ
        people no_occurence
1         Anne           48
2   Blackbeard           56
3       Edward           46
4         Lily           55
5 Mr. Anderson           55
6          Neo           51
7     Red John           60
8        Smith           56
```

...and take this to create a barplot for example:

```
require(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(occ, aes(x = people, y = no_occurence)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

This can probably get you started in creating other visualizations.